# Bogus IPv4 version after sending packet on c

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I have written a code to send icmp ping packets. However, packets are not sent correctly. I'm using the gnu iphdr and icmphdr for my packet. I was using wireshark after compiling my code and it showed me, that arp successfully found destination, but the packet I sent was corrupted (Bogus IPv4 version (1, must be 4)). What could possibly cause this? I can't find anything for now, I compared it with some other codes for ping command, and basically packet should be the same. Thank you.

**Wireshark:**

> 271 | 3.195079710 | Tp-LinkT_13:20:1a | Azurewav_fd:23:a9 | IPv4 | 42 | Bogus IPv4 version (1, must be 4)

**Code:**

```
struct iphdr *ip;
struct icmphdr *icmp;

//decimal version of ip addresses
subnet.ipDec = 2248190144;
subnet.ipDest = 2868947136;

//forming packet
uint16_t psize = sizeof(*icmp)+sizeof(*ip)+1;
char *packet;
packet=malloc(psize);
ip= (struct iphdr*) packet;
icmp= (struct icmphdr*)(ip+1);

//session identificators
unsigned int id = (unsigned int)rand();
unsigned int seq = (unsigned int)rand();

//filling packet with data
ip->version = 4;
ip->ihl = 4;
ip->tos = 0;
ip->tot_len = htons(psize);
ip->id = id;
ip->frag_off = 0;
ip->ttl = 64;
ip->protocol = IPPROTO_ICMP;
ip->saddr = subnet.ipDec;
ip->daddr = subnet.ipDest;
icmp->type = 8;
icmp->code = 0;
icmp->un.echo.id=id;
icmp->un.echo.sequence=seq;
icmp->checksum=icmpchecksum((unsigned short *)icmp, sizeof(struct icmphdr));

sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);

//destination for sendto
struct sockaddr_in destIP;
socklen_t destLen = sizeof(destIP);
destIP.sin_addr.s_addr=subnet.ipDest;
destIP.sin_family=AF_INET;

sendto(sock, &packet, psize, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &destIP, destLen);
```

Comment: hm, have you tried to simply write your `packet` to a file (`fwrite(.., packet)`) and look at the hexdump, or load it (somehow) into wireshark? That way, you could isolate problems that happen during your assembly of the packet from problems with your usage of the socket API?

Comment: `ip->ihl` should be 5

Comment: `sizeof(*icmp)+sizeof(*ip)+1;`what is the intention of the`+1` here ? Payload? Roundup to even? (should also mask with eg `0xfffe` )

Comment: After *fwrite* file was 8 bit long, and the packet in the wireshark does not even have those 8 bits inside (probably it's not the socket fault) | have changed it to 5, didn't work | yes, it was payload before, forgot to remove it. After removal nothing changed